# spring-boot, spring-boot-starter-data-jpa: database type NONE or Cannot find changelog location

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

me again, now with a spring-boot-starter-data-jpa Problem. I using spring-boot to access multiple databases. MongoDB went right, also Cassandra, last one PostgreSQL and JPA have some problems. i think my configuration may be wrong. Could you help me to figure it out? I used the spring-boot, spring-data-jpa reference and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa reference. Nothing helped. I found some threads at stakeoverflow, that use jdbc with hsql dependency because jpa won't function correctly [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26481580/4779586). I tried this myself but than i get a no qualifying bean error.

So i did a step back, included jpa and hsql, write a PostgresConfig class nothing helped. If i use the @EnableJpaRepositories Annotation i get a wired Error. See Stacktrace [Para 67.5.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/) Error... I didn't use this liquibase thingy, idk why there is an error... Otherwise if i won't use DataSourceBuilder my application.properties won't be read and i got the database type NONE error.

Some Source:
Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find changelog location: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] (please add changelog or check your Liquibase configuration)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at com.kage.bigdata.bida.Application.main(Application.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find changelog location: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] (please add changelog or check your Liquibase configuration)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.checkChangelogExists(LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 26 more
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.schema=bigdata

spring.datasource.platform=postgresql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=drop-create
```

Config:

```
package com.kage.bigdata.bida.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

/**
 *
 * @author bl4ckbird
 */
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.kage.bigdata.bida.repository.postgres")
public class PostgresConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()  {    
           return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();

    }


}
```

POM.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.kage.bigdata</groupId>
    <artifactId>bida</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Application:

```
package com.kage.bigdata.bida;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

/**
 *
 * @author bl4ckbird
 */
@SpringBootApplication


public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable { 
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class); 
        app.run(); 
    } 
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.kage.bigdata.bida.repository.postgres;

import com.kage.bigdata.bida.model.Question;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

/**
 *
 * @author bl4ckbird
 */
public interface QPostgresRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, String> {

}
```

QuestionEntity (multi-annotated(cassandra,mongo,jpa):

```
package com.kage.bigdata.bida.model;


import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;

/**
 *
 * @author bl4ckbird
 */
@Table
@Entity
public class Question implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @PrimaryKey
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @javax.persistence.Id
    private String id;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String question;



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Question[id=%s, Question='%s']",
                id, question);
    }
}
```

Autowired Service:

```
package com.kage.bigdata.bida.service.impl;

import com.kage.bigdata.bida.model.Question;

import com.kage.bigdata.bida.repository.cassandra.QCassandraRepository;
import com.kage.bigdata.bida.repository.QuestionRepository;
import com.kage.bigdata.bida.repository.postgres.QPostgresRepository;

import com.kage.bigdata.bida.service.QuestionService;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 *
 * @author bl4ckbird
 */

@Service
public class QuestionServiceImpl implements QuestionService{

    @Autowired
    QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @Autowired
    QCassandraRepository cassandraRepository;

    @Autowired
    QPostgresRepository postgresRepository;

    public QuestionServiceImpl(){};

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void test() {
        Question q = new Question();
        q.setQuestion("Frage");

        questionRepository.save(q);

        System.out.println(questionRepository.findAll()); 



        q.setQuestion("Frage2");


        cassandraRepository.save(q);

        System.out.println(cassandraRepository.findAll());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GOT IT WORKING! Finally... What i did: delete HSQLDB from pom deb. Put liquidbaseautoconfiguration.class to exclude... 1 line of Code and 8 hours code reading.. here my Configuration Class. Hope i could help somebody:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = 
            LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class
          )
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.kage.bigdata.bida.repository.postgres")
public class PostgresConfig {


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("postgres");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.kage.bigdata.bida.model");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(buildHibernateProperties());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(new Properties() {{
            put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", SpringSessionContext.class.getName());
        }});
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {{
            setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        }});
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }



    protected Properties buildHibernateProperties()
    {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", "false");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "false");

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("javax.persistence.validation.mode", "none");

        //Audit History flags
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag", "true");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate() {
        return new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager());
    }

}
```

Comment: Spring Boot will only configure Liquibase for you if it's on the classpath and, in this case, it is as it's a transitive dependency of `spring-data-cassandra`. You may want to try excluding it in your pom if you're not using it.

Comment: i did it as you can see, but nowhere is something written that cassandra has a transitive dependency on liquibase. Take me 8 hours to figure that out...and i think jpa has that transitive dependency because problem got active after i include spring-data-jpa

Comment: Thanks for the hint. to see dependencies : mvn dependency:tree

Answer (score 1):

You must exclude liquibase from the string-data-cassandra dependency like so :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```